# How should I go about reusing a stream in Go?

Tags: go

I have a struct `Artifact` and the following two functions of interest:

```
type Artifact struct {
    Name string
    ZipFile io.ReadWriter
}

func New(name string, files []string, zipArchiveStream io.ReadWriter) *Artifact {}
func (a *Artifact) Upload() error {}
```

So here's the problem: before passing that `io.ReadWriter` around, I was using the file name. There are three operations I need to do with the zip file:

1. Add the necessary files to it (i.e. Write)
2. Re-read it to calculate the SHA256 sum (i.e. Seek, Read)
3. Upload it to an S3 bucket (i.e. Seek, Read)

Well so before, when using the file name, I opened, closed, re-opened etc. for every operation. I started writing the unit tests however, and I realized my code was not really *testable* so I decided I would use `io.ReadWriter` so I could open files in real code usage, and pass buffers in testing.

The problem right now is that after the stream is read, its internal pointer needs to be reset in order to perform a second read (i.e. calculating the checksum, then uploading), but as far as I have read, streams cannot be rewinded. How should I approach this problem? because it seems like some is conceptually wrong with my current approach.

Comment: `.Seek(0,0)` doesn't rewind?

Comment: On files only. Isn’t that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you consider using the `io.ReadWriteSeeker` interface instead?

`bytes.Reader` implements `Seek`

Comment: Do you have any other recommendation on my situation, please? Is it a good practice to use readers/writers like this?

Comment: @Victor: I think it's fairly common to use interfaces for tests, wherein you substitute concrete things like files for "mock" things like byte buffers.

Comment: `bytes.Reader` does not implement `Write` as far as I can see in the docs? What is to be done in this situation?